# How can I build a fully decentralized daily poker competition?

Tags: polkadot

I'm looking to build a WSOP style texas holdem poker competition which includes multiple players turning up to play. With options like folding, raising, betting, etc. All in a fully decentralized way..

Here's a list of problems:
Where is the random number coming from? (A chainlink VRF system is cool but everyones cards can't be public on the pre-flop, so some kind of RANDAO system that passes through blocks will be needed..)
Could it be built on someone elses parachain or would it require a dedicated parachain?
Would you store the data of each game? (or delete it?)

What would be the solution for this?

P.S. I'm looking for devs interested in helping on this problem for paid roles..

Comment: I like that you are thinking through this! But please be more _concise_ and have _one question_ here that we can tackle with facts. This forum isn't generally a place to have a "chat" about how to scope your application architecture (sadly)

Answer (score 4):

I think privacy is one of the key components of gaming, and it's also one of the challenges of moving the whole game logic to the blockchain layer. Adding on top that you don't want to sacrifice interaction time for it. This applies to most of the games that are not providing perfect information like connect four to the players.

for privacy

- trusted executions using a privacy layer (https://youtu.be/yHlSUevPvH0) - hardware related
- zkSnarks https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ayelscjnx2E - computational power related
- hash & reveal (good for simple games, like Rock-Paper-Scissor) https://github.com/ajuna-network/pallet-ajuna-rps - players provide hashes of their interaction (hashed) and reveal at the end the seed and the choice.

For poker, I would suggest using trusted execution environments to get privacy and randomness without sacrificing speed (ex. ajuna network)

Answer (score 3):

The big problem after random data is private data which blockchain does not have privacy at all, so you must define a protocol to keep data encrypted in blockchain but at the end of each turn players should show their hands and it needs a way to be sure the player can not create a random hand for itself and should get the hand from the dealer, but if the dealer knows the hand it could be a way to fraud, at the end i have solved the problem by another type of miners who generate hands by solving a diffucult equity and keeps the hash of that data, sends the data to player and player solves another equity to create a random hand ... may be helpful :)